# Clojure: traversing map vectors and adding elements that repeat

Tags: clojure

I hope you are all well. Well, I am new to Clojure programming and would like some help. I have the following map vector:

```
(def curves [{:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 2 :value 3}
         {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 4}
         {:curve_buyer "curve3" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 2 :value 3}
         {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 3}
         {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 4 :value 4}
         {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 4}])
```

I need to do a check on that vector, where it checks the keys (:curve_buyer and :curve_seller) that have the same value. If they have the same value, I need to add quantity and value, otherwise return the map as is. Taking the map above I would have the following return.

```
(def curves [{:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 6 :value 7}
             {:curve_buyer "curve2" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2  :value 4}
             {:curve_buyer "curve3" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 2  :value 3}
             {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curva3" :quantity 4  :value 7}])
```

I need a function that does this. Any way using the clojure functions or an idea of a function that can solve my problem.

Thank you for your attention and I am willing for any clarification.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use *reduce* and *map*. you can make summary in first *reduce*. *group-by* looks simple, but it uses *reduce* for grouping, not for making summary.

```
(->> curves
     (reduce (fn [m {:keys [buyer seller q v]}]
               (update m [buyer seller]
                       #(-> %
                            (update :q (fnil + 0) q)
                            (update :v (fnil + 0) v))))
             {})
     (map (fn [[[buyer seller] m]]
            (assoc m :buyer buyer :seller seller))))
```

also you can use map as a key

```
(->> curves
     (reduce (fn [m {:keys [q v] :as curve}]
               (update m (select-keys curve [:buyer :seller])
                       #(-> %
                            (update :q (fnil + 0) q)
                            (update :v (fnil + 0) v))))
             {})
     (map (fn [[km sm]] (merge km sm))))
```

so as a function

```
(defn summary-list
  [l key-keys val-keys]
  (->> (reduce (fn [acc m]
                 (update acc (select-keys m key-keys)
                         #(reduce (fn [vm vk]
                                    (update vm vk
                                            (fnil + 0)
                                            (get m vk)))
                                  % val-keys)))
               {} l)
       (map (partial reduce merge))))
```

call like this

```
(summary-list curves [:curve_buyer :curve_seller] [:quantity :value])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output is probably wrong, because map `{:curve_buyer "curve2" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2  :value 4}` is not in `curves`.

This task can be solved with [`group-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) and [`merge-with`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge-with). First, divide maps into groups by given keys:

```
(def curves [{:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 2 :value 3}
             {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 4}
             {:curve_buyer "curve3" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 2 :value 3}
             {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 3}
             {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve2" :quantity 4 :value 4}
             {:curve_buyer "curve1" :curve_seller "curve3" :quantity 2 :value 4}])

(->> curves
     (group-by (juxt :curve_buyer :curve_seller)))
=>
{["curve1" "curve2"] [{:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve2", :quantity 2, :value 3}
                      {:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve2", :quantity 4, :value 4}],
 ["curve1" "curve3"] [{:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve3", :quantity 2, :value 4}
                      {:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve3", :quantity 2, :value 3}
                      {:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve3", :quantity 2, :value 4}],
 ["curve3" "curve2"] [{:curve_buyer "curve3", :curve_seller "curve2", :quantity 2, :value 3}]}
```

Then use `merge-with` to join maps in each group into one:

```
(->> curves
     (group-by (juxt :curve_buyer :curve_seller))
     (map (fn [[k v]] (apply merge-with 
                             (fn [o1 o2] (if (number? o1) (+ o1 o2) o1)) 
                             v))))
=>
({:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve2", :quantity 6, :value 7}
 {:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve3", :quantity 6, :value 11}
 {:curve_buyer "curve3", :curve_seller "curve2", :quantity 2, :value 3})
```

And as a function:

```
(defn summarize-by-keys [keys summary-fn list-of-maps]
  (->> list-of-maps
       (group-by (apply juxt keys))
       (map (fn [[k v]] (apply merge-with
                               summary-fn
                               v)))))

;; call it by:
(summarize-by-keys [:curve_buyer :curve_seller]
                   #(if (number? %1) (+ %1 %2) %1)
                   curves)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to go through each element of `curves` and create or update the corresponding element of the result in one pass.

```clj
(reduce (fn [res m]
          (let [{:keys [curve_buyer curve_seller quantity value]} m
                ;; idx is the index of the current buyer/seller
                ;; in the partial result or nil
                idx (first (keep-indexed (fn [i x]
                                           (when (and (= (:curve_buyer x) curve_buyer)
                                                      (= (:curve_seller x) curve_seller))
                                             i))
                                         res))]
            (if idx
              (update res
                      idx
                      #(assoc %
                              :quantity (+ quantity (:quantity %))
                              :value (+ value (:value %))))
              (conj res m))))
        []
        curves
```

The final result is:

```clj
[{:curve_buyer "curve1",
  :curve_seller "curve2",
  :quantity 6,
  :value 7}
 {:curve_buyer "curve1",
  :curve_seller "curve3",
  :quantity 6,
  :value 11}
 {:curve_buyer "curve3",
  :curve_seller "curve2",
  :quantity 2,
  :value 3}]
```

Note that vectors can be treated as associative collections, with the indices of the elements to be the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[net.cgrand.xforms :as x])

(->> curves
        (group-by (juxt :curve_buyer :curve_seller))
        (map last)
        (map (fn [xs] (into (first xs)
                          (x/multiplex
                              {:quantity (comp (map :quantity) (x/reduce +))
                               :value    (comp (map :value) (x/reduce +))}) xs))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it this way:

first we can think of the function to make a map out of every item, containing index key and values to summarize:

```
(defn mappify [ks vs item]
  {(select-keys item ks) (select-keys item vs)})


(mappify [:curve_buyer :curve_seller]
         [:quantity :value]
         (first curves))
;;=>{{:curve_buyer "curve1", :curve_seller "curve2"}
;;   {:quantity 2, :value 3}}
```

then you can mappify all the items, and merge them:

```
(->> curves
     (map #(mappify [:curve_buyer :curve_seller]
                    [:quantity :value] %))
     (apply merge-with (partial merge-with +))
     (map (partial apply into)))

 ;;({:curve_buyer "curve1",
 ;; :curve_seller "curve2",
 ;; :quantity 6,
 ;; :value 7}
 ;;{:curve_buyer "curve1",
 ;; :curve_seller "curve3",
 ;; :quantity 6,
 ;; :value 11}
 ;;{:curve_buyer "curve3",
 ;; :curve_seller "curve2",
 ;; :quantity 2,
 ;; :value 3})
```